# Select dataframe columns based on number in column name

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a group of dataframes each with many columns.  In each dataframe some of the columns are named as `Test_1`, `Test_2`, `Test_3` etc., with the total number of test columns varying.

Some (but not all!) of the tests have associated results.  Results are in their own columns, named as `Test_1_Result`, `Test_2_Result` etc.  Result are always in order, with no skipping (so no `Test_Result_4` without `Test_Result_3`).

There may also be any number of other non test/result columns in the dataframe.

Here's a toy example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Test_1 = c("Standard", "Standard", "Standard"),
  Test_1_Result = c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass"),
  Test_2 = c("Sepcial", "Special", "Special"),
  Test_2_Result = c("Pass", "Fail", "Fail"),
  Test_3 = c("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"),
  Test_4 = c(NA, NA, NA),
  Col_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  Col_2 = c(1.2, 2.2, 3.2),
  Other_Col = c(1.3, 2.3, 3.3)
)
```

What I want to do is remove the test columns that do not have a corresponding result column, ideally using `dplyr::select`.

I've been able to identify the highest result column like so, but have gotten no further

```
library(stringr)
numbs <- str_extract(names(df), "\\d_")[is.na(str_extract(names(df), "\\d_")) == FALSE]
numbs <- as.numeric(str_remove(numbs, "_"))
paste0("Test_", max(numbs), "_Result")
[1] "Test_2_Result"
```

What I'd like is this (`Test_3` and `Test_4` removed).

```
df_target <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Test_1 = c("Standard", "Standard", "Standard"),
  Test_1_Result = c("Pass", "Fail", "Pass"),
  Test_2 = c("Sepcial", "Special", "Special"),
  Test_2_Result = c("Pass", "Fail", "Fail"),
  Col_1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  Col_2 = c(1.2, 2.2, 3.2),
  Other_Col = c(1.3, 2.3, 3.3)
)
```

I understand that in this toy example it's simple to just use `dplyr::select(-Test_3, -Test_4)` but the real dataframe will have lots of test columns to remove.  I'd like to avoid entering them all manually.

Comment: Is it important for you to have the columns ordered the same way as in your expected output?

Comment: @tmfmnk No, column order is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not elegant at all but would remove the desired columns. This assumes the consistent naming/structure of the `Test_*` and `Test_*_Result` columns.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

test_cols <- str_remove(str_subset(names(df), "^Test_"), "_Result")
keep_these <- test_cols[duplicated(test_cols)]
drop_these <- test_cols[!test_cols %in% keep_these]
df %>% 
  select(-all_of(drop_these))

  Name   Test_1 Test_1_Result  Test_2 Test_2_Result Col_1 Col_2 Other_Col
1    A Standard          Pass Sepcial          Pass     1   1.2       1.3
2    B Standard          Fail Special          Fail     2   2.2       2.3
3    C Standard          Pass Special          Fail     3   3.2       3.3
```

Answer (score 1):

One option ignoring the order of columns could be:

```
df %>%
 select(which(duplicated(str_remove(names(.), "_Result"), fromLast = TRUE)),
        matches("^Name|_Result$|^Col|^Other_col"))

    Test_1  Test_2 Name Test_1_Result Test_2_Result Col_1 Col_2 Other_Col
1 Standard Sepcial    A          Pass          Pass     1   1.2       1.3
2 Standard Special    B          Fail          Fail     2   2.2       2.3
3 Standard Special    C          Pass          Fail     3   3.2       3.3
```

Comment: This is in the right direction, but it trades manually entering the columns to remove for manually entering columns to keep (or `matches` for them at least) and there can be quite a lot of those